# MinGW-w64 generates 32-bit binaries

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, mingw-w64

Why does my MinGW-w64 generates 32-bit binaries? They can't run if their stack size is more than ~2GB, compatibility mode is on Windows XP by default, and `-m64` option doesn't works (`64-bit mode is not compiled in.`).

Comment: Which gcc binaries do you use? Where did you get them from?

Comment: Consider tagging with C **or** C++ for more exposure. Despite `-w64` in the name, there are versions of MinGW-w64 that target both x32 and x64. And there's more than one distribution of it. Where did you get your compiler from?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have got it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/),
and I use Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Which exact file did you download? The installer, `mingw-w64-install.exe`? If so, it lets you choose if you want an x32 or x64 compiler.

Comment: @ssbssa See above

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, the problem solved.

Comment: You're welcome! On a side note, consider using a different MinGW distribution (the one you used has an outdated GCC). The two good ones are https://www.msys2.org/ and http://winlibs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which exact file did you download? The installer, `mingw-w64-install.exe`? If so, it lets you choose if you want an x32 or x64 compiler. Consider using a different MinGW distribution (the one you used has an outdated GCC). The two good ones are [msys2.org](https://msys2.org) and [winlibs.com](https://winlibs.com)  – [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat)